# Google API Explorer shows no API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm following this tutorial  [Google Cloud Endpoints Tutorial](http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/), I downloaded the [Sample Project](https://github.com/rominirani/MyAPIProject) and ran it. When I navigated to localhost:8888/_ah/api/explorer It doesnt show anything, only the loading on top. What's happening here?

[image]

It seems there's no problem in my console log but there's a warning

```
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
```

Comment: I suggest the following - 1) Make sure there are no errors while running the application 2) There are no compilation errors in your project 3) Are you able to add any Hello World Servlet and does that work 4) Could you try with a fresh project ?

Comment: It seems it's on my end. I tried running a Hello World servlet and navigated to the API explorer, it's the same screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating my appengine-java SDK.